# Nega-Zeckendorf representation

Tags: code-golf, integer, binary, fibonacci, encoding

### Background

Zeckendorf representation is a numeral system where each digit has the value of Fibonacci numbers (1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, ...) and no two consecutive digits can be 1.

[Nega-Zeckendorf representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem#Representation_with_negafibonacci_numbers) is an extension to this system that allows encoding of all integers, not just positive ones. Its base values are nega-Fibonacci numbers (regular Fibonacci numbers with alternating sign; 1, -1, 2, -3, 5, -8, 13, -21, ..., also derived by extending regular Fibonacci sequence to negative indices).

Donald Knuth proved that every integer has a unique representation as a sum of non-consecutive nega-Fibonacci numbers (0 is an empty sum). Therefore, the corresponding nega-Zeckendorf representation is unique for every integer. 0 is represented as an empty list of digits.

### Challenge

Given an integer (which can be positive, zero, or negative), compute its nega-Zeckendorf representation.

The output must consist of zeros and ones, either as numbers or characters. Output in either least-significant first or most-significant first order is acceptable (the latter is used in the test cases).

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
-10 = 101001
-9 = 100010
-8 = 100000
-7 = 100001
-6 = 100100
-5 = 100101
-4 = 1010
-3 = 1000
-2 = 1001
-1 = 10
0 = (empty)
1 = 1
2 = 100
3 = 101
4 = 10010
5 = 10000
6 = 10001
7 = 10100
8 = 10101
9 = 1001010
10 = 1001000

-11 = (-8) + (-3) = 101000
12 = 13 + (-1) = 1000010
24 = 34 + (-8) + (-3) + 1 = 100101001
-43 = (-55) + 13 + (-1) = 1001000010
(c.f. negafibonacci: 1, -1, 2, -3, 5, -8, 13, -21, 34, -55, ...)
```

Comment: [This stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41260776/9961151) contains a possible algorithm.

Comment: An ungolfed Mathematica implementation based on Knuth's proof: `m[a_] := Switch[Mod[a, 8], 1 | 5, a - 1, 0, a + 2, 4, a - 3, 2, 4 m[(a - 2)/4] + 1]; p[a_] := Switch[Mod[a, 4], 2, a - 2, 0, a + 1, 1 | 3, 2 m[(a - 1)/2]]; c[n_] := Nest[If[n > 0, p, m], 0, Abs@n];`

Comment: Is it acceptable to output 0 for 0?

Comment: @Jakque [No.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59456284#59456284)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
0BUJNÆḞḋƲ=ʋ1#ḢȯRB
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT4Awf9qZWxsef//MEJVSk7DhuG4nuG4i8ayPcqLMSPhuKLIr1JC/zEwxZJSICzDh8WS4bmYJCTigqwgS@KCrFn//w)

+3 bytes (`ḢȯR`) to output `[]` instead of `0`

I'm sure this can be beaten by some clever mathematical trick; this just counts up in binary, converts from nega-Zeckendorf and stops when it equals the input

### How it works

```
0BUJNÆḞḋƲ=ʋ1#ḢȯRB - Main link. Takes n on the left
          ʋ       - Group the previous 4 links into a dyad f(k, n):
 B                -   Convert k to binary
  U               -   Reverse the bits
        Ʋ         -   Group the previous 4 links into a monad g(bin(k)):
   J              -     Indices
    N             -     Negate
     ÆḞ           -     nth Fibonacci number
       ḋ          -     Dot product with bin(k)
         =        -   Does g(bin(k)) equal n?
0          1#     - Find the first integer k such that f(k, n) is true
             Ḣ    - Extract k
              ȯR  - If k = 0, replace with []
                B - Convert to binary
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>89</strike>, 87 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,a=-1,b=1,i=0:0<b*n<=b*b-i%2and f"1{f(n+a):0>{i}}"or n and f(n,b,a-b,i+1)or""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDRToQwEHznKzYkBnpXki6cnpLr/Yj6QKHkGrUQqIlK@HZckIJNpp3uzO622367W2Ozaarle/GhqgIsL2SCXEnkRopcXNTBXqQ6qMTcpYWtoA5xqGN7LFguroMZx7DpwMIixZYrXiSKmyOypgvDyene9SAhTlBwSJ4Ij4Qz4YFwTzgRMkJKQA5ko50uFCOJHGQkP6VRNgoW6K9Wl05Xc9kIBQqBEQdiRIRnYmdexS2GPrb7vfJ3zvvC1vDq3tK32ltjX89b/5lxb0syC8qbLt90tzz/5TM9n8pZnxlmJNc0T8c1GAs/po2XCXLwn2Z5ALTmmdaxY8ul7Yx1cR0OboTkCtHQjxEMa5tnLWX/OoZs@gU)

[Old version](https://tio.run/##TVDRToQwEHznKzY8SHtXku7d6Sm53o@oDxRKrlELgZqohG/HBSnYZNrpzuxuu823v9XuOI6Ves8/dJmDE7lKUWiFwiqZyYveuYvSO50ye4c8dyVUMfYVc/ucZ/La22GI6xYczBJzQos81cLukddtHI/edL4DBSxFKSB9IjwSzoQHwj3hRDgSDgQUQDba6UIxkshBRvJTGmWj5JH5akzhTTmVTVCilJgIIEZEBiY3FlRcYxhimz8of@e0z2wJL@41fa29Ng71gvWfGbe2JPOouJnizbTz818@D@dTMekTwyPJFc3TCwPWwY9t2DxBAeHTPIuA1jTTink@X5rWOs@quPcDpFdI@m5IoF/aPBulutch5uMv)

Uses the fact that each negative term in the negbonacci equals minus the sum of all preceding positive terms and, similarly, each positive term is 1 minus the sum of all preceding negative terms.
This is used to set up a direct recursion.

Test bed "borrowed" from @Noodle9.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>19</s> 18 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞bõš.ΔRSƶÅfāÉ·<*OQ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9vc2FiaWX//@KInmLDtcWhLs6UUlPGtsOFZsSBw4nCtzwqT1H//y0xMA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##ATwAw/9vc2FiaWX/VChUxbh2ecKpPyIg4oaSICI//@KInmLDtcWhLs6UUlPGtsOFZsSBw4nCtzwqT8KuUf99LP8).

**Explanation:**

```python
∞                  # Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,4,5,...]
 b                 # Convert each to a binary string
  õš               # Prepend an empty string (for edge case 0)
    .Δ             # Find the first value which is truthy for:
      R            #  Reverse the binary string
       S           #  Convert it to a list of bits
        ƶ          #  Multiply each by its 1-based index
         Åf        #  Get the n'th Fibonacci number for each
           ā       #  Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping)
            É      #  Check for each whether it's odd: [1,0,1,0,1,...]
             ·     #  Double each: [2,0,2,0,2,...]
              <    #  Subtract each by 1: [1,-1,1,-1,1,...]
               *   #  Multiply it to the Fibonacci numbers at the same positions
                O  #  Sum them together
                 Q #  And check if it's equal to the (implicit) input-integer
                   # (after which the found result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 74 bytes

Output format: least-significant first.

```javascript
f=(n,k)=>(g=(k,a,b)=>k&&k%2*a+g(k>>1,b-a,a,s+=k%2))(k,1,s='')^n?f(n,-~k):s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FU1LDoIwFNx7ircR@uS1schKUowLT2HQFATUYkuoMTFGr45lMcl8M3f90r4eb8OTW3dppqlVzJJBVbBOMUOaqsBNFJllutJJx0xRSKq4DolPVHARQ02SV3GMJ7trw5z/DG79lB@FEDP246jfLJVYioceGDsTWARVgAUOco0EXEoCmRKkWRDZphStGw@6vjI79z4LgNpZ7/pG9K4LFxB@EPPFF6c/)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>137 129</s> 119 bytes

```ruby
n=->x{x<2?x:n[x-2]-n[x-1]}
z=->x,u=0{i,y=0,u.to_s(2)
y.bytes.sum{|b|b%2*n[y.size+i-=1]}!=x||y=~/11+/?z[x,u+1]:y[0..-2]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/dbsIwDIXv/RQZEhI/SYjT8qsFHqSrpnXrtF7QIdpKCS17deaWBG6ST7bPOfa5ydztVhqxt6191Qe7KxMrdCr6D9MrXPoWb4xqC@6M4o2sf9@riZ6Ck5mr80pWzbHtsi4b61mZOFkVl3xeCEPiF2O7zpm/BeJ8cbgk5DPHdOcSJSVlXG/JTCAxKi4QOWquYy7iKJX5x@dP29nudC7K@puNxtEXM3s23lRv5Ygzyxm5kQHJmWGoUCkEsR2YUIHYeFbE68A0s7oz9vVlYKrH3gdE5KdBaN8HgQNBHzbJj6faTWEogR@BuwghDpawDKGwCmvBOiwLG08I28cSCvw16h6PGMapox83KNDxUzPsHj1l9PwD)

- Saved 8 Bytes thanks to @ovs suggestion to use =~(find) instead of match
- probably not the golfiest but at least I solved this complicated task.

n=->x{..}  # nega-fib(x)
z=->x,u=0{ # starts from 0
y=u.to_s 2 # binary representation

we convert y to an array of nega+fibs or 0.
If that sum is ==x and if no 1's are next to each other we return y  with last bit removed, else we try next u

Comment: `y.match(/1{2,}/)` can be shortened to `y=~/11+/`.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 83 bytes

```javascript
t=>(h=i=>i&i/2|t-(g=(i,p=0,q=1)=>i&&g(i>>1,q,p-q)+i%2*q)(i)?h(++i):i)``.toString(2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxNDoIwFAav4kbynm0RWAqvHsILQJCfz5CWQuPKu1fYzGKSmU/37fZ@wxqN8@8hjZKiWJoFYpHhXv2ioUkIepVCByn59NlEsLbUQa8msMK1ugUm8HMmpcAPcNvm0b/iBjdRxWn0G0FMWdRo5KRS3Hu3@2XIF3/c9GU8eq7THw)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
╘ïâ_h╒m*fh╒¥∞(m*Σk=▼
```

Outputs in least-significant first order (so the test cases in reversed).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1BmH1x9eFJ/xaOqkXK00EHVo6aOOeRq5WucWZ9s@mrbn/39dQwMuXUsuXQsuXXMuXTMuXVMuXRMuXWMuXSMuXUMuAy5DLiMuYy4TLlMuMy5zLgsuSy5DAwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
                   ▼ # Do-while false with pop:
╘                    #  Discard everything from the stack
 ï                   #  Push the 0-based loop-index
  â                  #  Convert it to a binary-list
   _                 #  Duplicate it
    h                #  Push the length of this list (without popping)
     ╒               #  Pop and push a list in the range [1,length]
      m*             #  Multiply the integers at the same positions together
        f            #  Get the n'th Fibonacci number for each
         h╒          #  Push a [1,length] ranged list again (without popping)
           ¥         #  Modulo-2 on each
            ∞        #  Double each
             (       #  Subtract each by 1
              m*     #  Multiply the integers at the same positions again
                Σ    #  Sum this list together
                 k=  #  Check whether it's equal to the input-integer
                     # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result,
                     # which is the binary-list we've duplicated)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 60 bytes

```
ＮθＦ²⊞υ±ιＷ∧θ⁼›θ§υ±³›θ§υ±¹⊞υ↨…⮌υ²±¹Ｗ›Ｌυ²¿⁼›θ§υ±³›θ⊟υ0«1≧⁺§υ±¹θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVBLa8JAED7rrxg8zUAKjT16ilKK0ErwH2zjmF1YN8k@1FL87evGF@1BD87xm@81U0lhq0boGOemDX4RNt9ssaPJcN1YwDFBGZzEkMGCa@EZFaXdTirNgIVZYZfBexeEdvhhORFsjxR@bla8/yN7I6IMHlJyOs0tcCoc4@yn0jyTTYtL3rJNSEg@Y/qnuhW6@n@yqb28UAnUGvCpkmXKDedSVhmPo9dRCmPtGH6HgwuW99jgS7SFc6o2S1VLj6UO7s6RGfTvPcSY5/Flq48) Link is to verbose version of code. Based on the algorithm in the linked Stack Overflow question. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the integer.

```
Ｆ²⊞υ±ι
```

Start building up the negated nega-Fibonacci sequence with `0, -1`.

```
Ｗ∧θ⁼›θ§υ±³›θ§υ±¹
```

Until enough terms have been generated to calculate the nega-Zeckendorf representation...

```
⊞υ↨…⮌υ²±¹
```

Push the difference between the last two terms to the sequence.

```
Ｗ›Ｌυ²
```

While sufficient terms of the sequence remain:

```
¿⁼›θ§υ±³›θ⊟υ0
```

If the integer does not fall between the third last and the last term (removing the last term as we go), then output a `0`.

```
«1≧⁺§υ±¹θ
```

Otherwise output a `1` and add the (originally second) last term to the integer, which brings it closer to zero (since it has the opposite sign; see the linked question to explain why this works).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>125</s> <s>97</s></sup> 93 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=0:n-g(k)and f(n,k+1)or bin(k)[2:-1]
g=lambda k,a=0,b=1:k and k%2*a+g(k>>1,b-a,a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDtToMwFP3PU9wsMVBXkl42nZJ0LzL3o7CyEbQjUBN12bPjAVcmySm35@NeuO23P53dahgq/W4@ioMhJxutcpcek0YYd6AqAbNkce6oqB3IXZanvI@OIdBIo5UsNOcNjYHmIXs0S8S3W5ZFaqQRg7e970lTkrKSlL4CL8AGeAaegDWwAjKAJcGGExdwkOCAEX7EkGYlIvvV2tLbw9g2ZsVKcSwJFQoVKnWvgsozx4G7@4Py9x7PqbrRN/ccn3vPg0O/YP1n5vtYyCIqT7ZsbDd9/ttntlmXoz5WvIJcYeFeWqod/dRtMm1QUvhpkUeEZ9xplXgxXdqudj6pFhd/pXRL8aW/xnS5jdlZrfv9dSGGXw)

*Port of [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)'s [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236677/9481).*

Outputs most-significant first.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 19 bytes

```
ḟö=⁰ṁ_z*z*İ_İf↔ΘmḋN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AWcAmP9odXNr/21vc@KCgf/huJ/Dtj3igbDhuYFfeip6KsSwX8SwZuKGlM6YbeG4i07///9bLTEwLC05LC04LC03LC02LC01LC00LC0zLC0yLC0xLDAsMSwyLDMsNCw1LDYsNyw4LDksMTBd)

```
                mḋ  # get the binary digits of each number in
                  N # the infinite list of integers
               Θ    # and prepend an empty list of no digits;
ḟö                  # now, return the first set that satisfies:
              ↔     # the digits reversed
      z*            # zipped by multiplication with
        z*İ_İf      # the negative negafibonacci sequence
                    # (=fibonacci sequence zipped by multiplication
                    # with powers of -1)
    ṁ_              # all negated and summed
  =⁰                # is equal to the input
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 240 bytes

```
=LET(q,SEQUENCE(1,18),d,SEQUENCE(2^18-1),x,DEC2BIN(INT(d/2^9),9)&DEC2BIN(MOD(d,2^9),9),y,FILTER(x,ISERROR(FIND(11,x))),IF(A1,XLOOKUP(A1,MMULT(MID(y,q,1)*1,TRANSPOSE(-1*ROUND((-((1+5^0.5)/2)^(19-q))/5^0.5,0))),REPLACE(y,1,FIND(1,y)-1,)),""))
```

### Explanation

```
=LET(q,SEQUENCE(1,18),                              # q = [1..18] horizontal
     d,SEQUENCE(2^18-1),                            # d = [1..2^18-1] vertical
     x,DEC2BIN(INT(d/2^9),9)&DEC2BIN(MOD(d,2^9),9), # x = 18 digit binary representations of d
     y,FILTER(x,ISERROR(FIND(11,x))),               # y = x with all items containing "11" removed
IF(A1,                                    # if A1 <> 0 then
      XLOOKUP(A1,                         #   match A1 to 
              MMULT(                      #   the matrix multiplication of
                MID(y,q,1)*1,             #   the digits of y times
                TRANSPOSE(-1*ROUND((-((1+5^0.5)/2)^(19-q))/5^0.5,0))), 
                                          #   the first 18 digits if the nega-Fibonacci series
              REPLACE(y,1,FIND(1,y)-1,)), #   return the corresponding y with leading zeros removed
      ""))                                # else ""
```

Lists all valid binary representations upto 18 digits and finds the match to the number in A1.  Works for [-4180 .. 2584].

Comment: You can get this down to 228 bytes by using `Column()` and `Row()`, and by using `int()` instead of `round()` -  `=LET(q,COLUMN(A:R),d,ROW(1:262143),x,DEC2BIN(INT(d/2^9),9)&DEC2BIN(MOD(d,2^9),9),y,FILTER(x,ISERROR(FIND(11,x))),IF(A1,XLOOKUP(A1,MMULT(1*MID(y,q,1),TRANSPOSE(-INT((-((1+5^0.5)/2)^(19-q))/5^0.5))),REPLACE(y,1,FIND(1,y)-1,)),""))`

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 111 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:x<0 or f(x-2)-f(x-1)
g=lambda a,n=0:a-sum(f(i)for i in range(n)if n>>i&1)and g(a,n+1)or bin(n)[2:-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY1BCsIwEEX3PcXQhcxgAkndBdOLiIuUNnHATktaoZ4@xoUbV3/x3uOv7/2xyKWU6J9hHsYAhzuuBpYMEQ/dkf6OpSb9eFDijQt6e80YkSlWlYEFcpA0oRBHkL7nk6UgIySswdlStQaWim@d0/Ze/jJtjbKGXANrZtmRVev7VuVpzZjqC1H5AA)